# Mysql timesheet calculation based on different events

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql for attendance (id, staff_id, created_time, in_out, tran_time, remarks).

in_out is a flagging column and have possible 4 inputs (I -> checked_in, O -> out for the day, B -> out for break, and C -> came from break). created time is timestamp column for the recording time, and tran_time is also a timestamp column having full date and time for the attendance.

I want to calculate total working time and break time spent by every staff on every day, lets say a view Timesheet having (staff_id, date, first_in_time, last_out_time, total_working_hours and total_break_hours).

There is a catch like every staff can have multiple inputs of in/out and break in out for any day. and also there could be a chance user do not input / punch his going time or coming back from break.

If user dont check-out, consider 8hours working, 
and If user do not return from break, consider out for the day.

I am stuck and new to Mysql. Table data screenshot is attached.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What should be done with shits starting in one calendar day and ending in the next (e.g. 23:00 - 07:30 shifts)?

Comment: `and also there could be a chance user do not input / punch his going time or coming back from break.` and therefore the whole approach starts to falls apart. SQL isn't going to fix that.

Comment: You need to do 3 things to save this question from being closed. `1. sample data`: provide some data, as text, not an image, include some exceptions like not recording a the end of a break  `2. expected result`: from the data you provide, what should the result be (yes: do this manually, maybe a spreadsheet) `3. attempt a query` we are not a free coding service and a question/answer service with answers provided by volunteers

Comment: @Used_By_Already What should appropriate approach you recommend from your experience? Regarding your second comment: 1. Morning & Evening Shifts are of standards 7 hours (0700-1400, 1400-2100). 2. Night Shift is 10 hours (2100-0700) 3. If user is not punching out (leaving it empty, considering time in or out till end of remaining hours) . These things are managed at form level directly but no inserts in dbs.

sample data is attached as sql script.